# Spawning multiple sh scripts in tcl makes it parallel process or child process?

Tags: multithreading, parallel-processing, tcl, spawn

I am spawning multiple sh (sipp) scripts from a tcl script . I want to know those scripts will run in parallel or as a child process? Because I want to run it in parallel.

If I use threads extension then do I need to use any other packages along with that?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: which OS?? for threading, you need to install thread enabled TCL

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Tcl can quite easily run multiple subprocesses in parallel. The way you do so depends on how you want to handle what those subprocesses do. (Bourne shell — sh — scripts work just fine as subprocesses.) *None of these require threads.* You can use threads too, but they're not necessary for just running subprocesses as, from Tcl's perspective at least, subprocess handling is a purely I/O-bound matter.

For more details, please narrow down (in another question) which type of subprocess handling you want to do.

### Fire and Forget

If you don't care about tracking the subprocesses at all, just set them going in the background by putting a `&` as the last word to `exec`:

```
exec /bin/sh myscript.sh &
```

### Keeping in Touch

To keep in touch with the subprocess, you need to `open` a pipeline (and use this weird stanza to do so; put the arguments inside a list with a `|` concatenated on the front):

```
set thePipe [open |[list /bin/sh myscript.sh]]
```

You can then `read`/`gets` from the pipe to get the output (yes, it supports `fileevent` and asynchronous I/O on all platforms). If you want to write to the pipe (i.e., to the subprocess's stdin) open with mode `w`, and to both read and write, use mode `r+` or `w+` (doesn't matter which, as it is a pipe and not a file). Be aware that you have to be a bit careful with pipes; you can get deadlocked or highly confused. I recommend using the asynchronous I/O style, with `fconfigure $thePipe -blocking 0`, but that's quite a bit different to a synchronous style of I/O handling.

### Great Expectations

You can also use the Expect extension to work with multiple spawned subprocesses at once. To do that, you *must* save the id from each `spawn` in its own variable, then pass that id to `expect` and `send` with the `-i` option. You probably want to use `expect_background`.

```
set theId [spawn /bin/sh myscript.sh]
expect_background {
    -i $theId
    "password:" {
        send -i $theId "$mypass\r"
        # Etc.
    }
}
# Note that [expect_background] doesn't support 'timeout'
```

Comment: Thanks for answering. I am using Expect already. I am using expect package to stop those sipp scripts I am running. But I am a little confused in understanding that when I hit multiple scripts one by one and I save their spawn id in different variable, then those scripts are running in parallel or not. According to your answer, they are running in parallel, right?

Comment: @Abhi Expect can run them in parallel, yes. It doesn't really do so (usefully) by default just because the default ID is really stored in a global variable. Be aware that there's a global (across _all_ processes on the system) limit on the number of virtual terminals, which is what expect uses to implement things.

Comment: Yes, I am saving value in some variable from global variable after running every script. It runs multiple scripts in parallel but shows execution of only one script in the terminal. That gave me a little of doubt in believing that it is running multiple scripts in parallel.
Thank you for the help, I got the answer to my main problem.